# Flutter: delete calendar events in Gmail

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-notification

I'm creating some local notifications for my users to remain them different events. I achieved this by using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications. These notifications are scheduled and can be removed easily.

I was thinking in other hand to move this to the private calendar wit Gmail. I have done this in the past and I know how to create them but I was wondering if I could remove also them.

In my app I have different portfolios. These contain rents and each rent has leases. When the user creates a lease an event is created with the different payment days.

If the user deletes either the event, the lease, the rent or the portfolio, I need to remove automatically all the notifications. Right now, since this is created with local_notifications I can do it, but would it be possible by having the events created in Gmail?
Could I created/remove a bunch of events without displaying the Gmail calendar app?